# How to throw a Customized InputMismatchException java?

Tags: java

I want to throw an `InputMismatchException` with the message `Value must contain only numbers`.

The code below compiles okay, but the catch block does not display the message from the throw block argument.

Without writing an `Exception` class, is it not possible to do this, or am I writing it wrong.

I am getting `null` from the print statement.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class X {

    public void getInt() throws Exception{   
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            scan.nextInt();
            throw new InputMismatchException("value must contain only number");
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); \\ Expected "value must contain number
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]arsgs) throws Exception{
        X x = new X();
        x.getInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [Scanner.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29), you can see that it throws its own `InputMismatchException`. Therefore, this Exception is being thrown before your throw code is reached, and the message from the Exception will be from the `nextInt()` call itself.

Comment: is there no way to change the message from Scanner?

Comment: You could print out the intended error message in your 'catch' block, rather than printing 'e.getMessage()'. That would remove the need to throw your own Exception.

Comment: That's educating. Maybe I am left with catching and re-throwing new Exception("Message").

Comment: Yea, that's another avenue you could take. Catch the `InputMismatchException` youself, and simply throw a new `InputMismatchException` with the message that you want it to have. This is a fairly common practice, as sometimes Exception messages don't fit well with the context of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Exception thrown from `scan.nextInt();` line. So its not reaching throw clause. Hence message was not initialized

Answer (score 0):

So.

1. If you provide number as input,your catch statement will print the messgae.
2. If you pass string as number `scan.nextInt()`,will throw exception and control will be directly transfered to catch block,which is why you are getting null.It will never execute your `throw new InputMismatchException("value must contain only number");` ,line.

You can write sth like below.

```
try {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        scan.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enter a valid number `scan.nextInt()` passes and your custom `InputMismatchException` is thrown with the expected message.
**But** if you enter something other, a letter for example, the `scan.nextInt();` throws `InputMismatchException` itself with no custom message. Thats why `getMessage()` returns `null`.
You need to catch the Exception from the `nextInt` and throw your own.

```
try{
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    scan.nextInt();               
}catch (InputMismatchException e){
    throw new InputMismatchException("value must contain only number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `throw new InputMismatchException` inside the catch like this:

```
   }catch (InputMismatchException e){
      throw new InputMismatchException("value must contain only number");
  // System.out.println(e.getMessage()); // Expected "value must contain number
```

With you can have an error message.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly,**

You want the exception to be raised with your custom message when user enter anything other than a number .. So thats your goal.. For that you can either create a new CustomException or you can just print it when you catch the exception...

**Secondly,**
You are attempting to call

`throw new InputMismatchException("value must contain only number");`

Which wont give you the expected result because the scanner class throws the `InputMismatchException` not your class..

So the InputMismatchException thrown by the Scanner class doesnt contain your required error message ..

To get your expected output try this..

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class X {

public void getInt() throws Exception
{   
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a number");
   handleException();
}
public static void main(String[]arsgs) throws Exception{
    X x = new X();
    x.getInt();
}

public void handleException()
{
    try
    {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       scan.nextInt();
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e)
    {
        System.out.println("value must contain only number");
    }        
}
}
```

The advantage in this would be you can call this method anytime to get required error message .. Which is almost similar to what you wanted i.e. you wanted InputMismatchException to print your error message.